# abp gives duplicate key exception for permissiongrants but can't change the values it tries to seed

Tags: c#, abp

I need to change my work project from single tenancy to multitenant. When doing so I was triying to seed the tenants to the database following the documentation, this is all working fine. But after seeding the tenants and making my entities multitenant.

I allways get an DbException saying that in dbo.AbpPermissionGrants are duplicate keys. I understand this is needed for permissions and roles but I don't seed roles with duplicate names.

The entity in question is always the same namely: "(38b387c6-5ce6-b9f8-736e-3a0e5e104886, Admin, R, Admin)".

I already changed tried changing my roles, deleting, changing, ...
Nothing helps I always get a duplicate.

If any of you have an idea to fix this please let me know.